# Cannot get jQuery to work when using webpack 5

Tags: jquery, webpack, webpack-5

I am trying to change a legacy application to use webpack 5.

I have added this in `home.js`:

```
import $ from "jquery";
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

When I build the project with webpack, in the bundled file, jquery selectors get transformed like this:

`$("#signUpModal").modal("show");`

becomes

`q()("#signUpModal").modal("show");`

And the button that opened the signUpModal in the old code now generates this error when clicked:

```
Uncaught TypeError: q()(...).modal is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It was not jQuery that wasn't working. It was Bootstrap. I had required boostrap's sass files but not its javascript files. Once I added `import 'bootstrap';` the modal worked fine.